# Can anyone tell me why my html-sections are overlayed?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've really tried everything i know, so i hope someone here can help me now^^

I'm building a html-webpage(http://www.stollhoferfest.at/test.php) containing different sections based on bootstrap. Everything worked fine until I added my last big section called "dirndljumping". Somehow an empty, white part of this section overlays the section ("kuppeltrophy") before.

Can anyone tell me why it isn't attached at the end of "kuppeltrophy"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see you use twitter-bootstrap in you page. So to render sections well, you need to wrap each of them into bootstrap `row` and to wrap both rows into bootstrap `container-fluid`:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <section id="kuppeltrophy"...
   </section>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <section id="dirndljumping"...
   </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: aaaah great :D i should really read the bootstrap-doc ;) thank you!

Comment: any idea why my "kuppeltrophy" intro-section doesn't fill in the whole page like "dirndljumping" intro?

Comment: you can add `height:100vh` to this: `#kuppeltrophy .intro .intro-body {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100vh;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Your sections are not block element you can simply fix this , you need to set `float:left` for each sections, like

```
#about {
 float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, have you checked your media queries, because this white space is gone at smaller sizes?

Also, I can see that you have

```
<section id="about" class="container content-section text-center">
```

which is occupying 1170x1306px and a padding of 250 on the top. I'm guessing you have some css for a container class or something that has transferred over to this and is boosting the padding or dimensions.

Let me know if this helps! And always try to use the "inspect" function in the browser if you didn't try this already. It'll help see what is happening in different areas that you might not have caught.

Best of luck,

Jake